# Google Cloud - Compute Engine - Error starting instance when attached disk in READ_ONLY

Tags: ssh, disk, google-compute-engine

I have a instance (`F1-Micro`) and a root persistent disk (10GB) on Google Cloud, Compute Engine service. When I start an instance and attach a disk in `READ_WRITE` the instance starts normally, executes my startup script and I can access through SSH. However, when I change the disk mode parameter to `READ_ONLY` the instance apparently starts normally and I can't do SSH giving me a timeout connection. Also, my startup script does not start. I suspect that or I need to attach more one root persistent disk with `READ_WRITE` permission or I need to setup some configuration in my disk. Someone could give me insight about what are happening? Below I give some data and logs:

Body Request:

```
instance = {
        'name': instance_name,
        'machineType': machine_type_url,
        'disks': [{
            'index' : 0,
            'autoDelete': 'false',
            'boot': 'true',
            'type': 'PERSISTENT',
            'mode' : 'READ_ONLY', # READ_ONLY, READ_WRITE
            'deviceName' : root_disk_name,
            'source' : source_root_disk
          }],
        'networkInterfaces': [{
          'accessConfigs': [{
            'type': 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT',
            'name': 'External NAT'
           }],
          'network': network_url
        }],
        'serviceAccounts': [{
             'email': service_email,
             'scopes': scopes
        }]
    }
```

Log of started instance on GC-CE:

```
Changing serial settings was 0/0 now 3/0
Start bios (version 1.7.2-20131007_152402-google)
No Xen hypervisor found.
Unable to unlock ram - bridge not found
Ram Size=0x26600000 (0x0000000000000000 high)
Relocating low data from 0x000e10a0 to 0x000ef780 (size 2161)
Relocating init from 0x000e1911 to 0x265d07a0 (size 63291)
CPU Mhz=2601
=== PCI bus & bridge init ===
PCI: pci_bios_init_bus_rec bus = 0x0
=== PCI device probing ===
Found 4 PCI devices (max PCI bus is 00)
=== PCI new allocation pass #1 ===
PCI: check devices
=== PCI new allocation pass #2 ===
PCI: map device bdf=00:03.0  bar 0, addr 0000c000, size 00000040 [io]
PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 0, addr 0000c040, size 00000040 [io]
PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 1, addr febff000, size 00001000 [mem]
PCI: init bdf=00:01.0 id=8086:7110
PIIX3/PIIX4 init: elcr=00 0c
PCI: init bdf=00:01.3 id=8086:7113
Using pmtimer, ioport 0xb008, freq 3579 kHz
PCI: init bdf=00:03.0 id=1af4:1004
PCI: init bdf=00:04.0 id=1af4:1000
Found 1 cpu(s) max supported 1 cpu(s)
MP table addr=0x000fdaf0 MPC table addr=0x000fdb00 size=240
SMBIOS ptr=0x000fdad0 table=0x000fd9c0 size=269
Memory hotplug not enabled. [MHPE=0xffffffff]
ACPI DSDT=0x265fe1f0
ACPI tables: RSDP=0x000fd990 RSDT=0x265fe1c0
Scan for VGA option rom
WARNING - Timeout at i8042_flush:68!
All threads complete.
Found 0 lpt ports
Found 0 serial ports
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@0,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@1,0
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@2,0
...
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@255,0
Scan for option roms
Searching bootorder for: HALT
drive 0x000fd950: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520
Space available for UMB: 000c0000-000eb800
Returned 122880 bytes of ZoneHigh
e820 map has 6 items:
  0: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 = 1 RAM
  1: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 = 2 RESERVED
  2: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 = 2 RESERVED
  3: 0000000000100000 - 00000000265fe000 = 1 RAM
  4: 00000000265fe000 - 0000000026600000 = 2 RESERVED
  5: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 = 2 RESERVED
Unable to lock ram - bridge not found
Changing serial settings was 3/2 now 3/0
enter handle_19:
  NULL
Booting from Hard Disk...
Booting from 0000:7c00
[    1.386940] i8042: No controller found
Loading, please wait...

INIT: version 2.88 booting

[[36minfo[39;49m] Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel S.
[....] Starting the hotplug events dispatcher: udevd[?25l[?1c7[1G[[32m ok [39;49m8[?25h[?0c.
[....] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events...[?25l[?1c7[1G[[32m ok [39;49m8[?25h[?0cdone.
[....] Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...[    8.524814] piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3:     SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
[?25l[?1c7[1G[[32m ok [39;49m8[?25h[?0cdone.
[....] Activating swap...[?25l[?1c7[1G[[32m ok [39;49m8[?25h[?0cdone.
[....] Checking root file system...fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.ext4: Operation not permitted while trying to open /dev/sda1
You must have r/w access to the filesystem or be root
fsck died with exit status 8
[?25l[?1c7[1G[[31mFAIL[39;49m8[?25h[?0c[31mfailed (code 8).[39;49m
[....] An automatic file system check (fsck) of the root filesystem failed. A manual fsck     must be performed, then the system restarted. The fsck should be performed in maintenance     mode with the root filesystem mounted in read-only mode. ...[?25l[?1c7[1G[[31mFAIL[39;49m8[?    25h[?0c [31mfailed![39;49m
[....] The root filesystem is currently mounted in read-only mode. A maintenance shell will     now be started. After performing system maintenance, press CONTROL-D to terminate the     maintenance shell and restart the system. ...[?25l[?1c7[1G[[33mwarn[39;49m8[?25h[?0c                 [33m(warning).[39;49m
sulogin: root account is locked, starting shell
root@localhost:~#
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in assuming that the boot disk for a GCE instance needs to appear in read-write mode. The [documentation for root persistent disks](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#usingrootpd) says:

> To start an instance with an existing root persistent disk in gcutil,
>   provide the boot parameter when you attach the disk. When you create a
>   root persistent disk using a Google-provided image, you must attach it
>   to your instance in read-write mode. If you try to attach it in
>   read-only mode, your instance may be created successfully, but it
>   won't boot up correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I understand in parts what you are saying. This part 'When you create a root persistent disk ... you must attach it to your instance in read-write mode' sounds to me that it need to be in RW only when I'm creating a root persistent disk for the first time. In my case I already have this disk created with a image and only want to boot without overwriting anything inside. Are there a way to accomplish that? My main objective is only to execute an algorithm that consume a task X in a SQS and write the result Y in a NoSQL database without need to write anything in HD.

Comment: The persistent disk used for boot always needs to be mounted in RW mode.  If you want to have an image that has nothing written to it, you can use one PD to boot from, and use a different PD in RO mode that has your application on it.